# Generar Thumbnails con php

Tags: php

Quiero generar miniaturas para las imagenes que se suben a mi pagina para guardarlas en mi servidor. He leido acerca de varias librerias pero mi host no me permite instalar librerias externas. ?Alguno sabe de alguna forma para generar miniaturas con buena calidad?.

Comment: ¿Sabes si tu servidor tiene activadas las extensiones `GD` o `Imagemagick`?

Comment: Puedes crearte una clase de php , que te las genere. Tu servidor te prohibe extensiones , pero dudo que no te permita una clases php que te genere los thumnails de una carpeta a otra y fuera cuando lo ejecutes con *php clase_imagen.php* .